# How to connect local Postgres database not synchronizing to Heroku production database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, npm

I have an application deployed on Heroku but for some reason when I create the database locally it does not get applied to the actual database on heroku and I'm not sure why this is happening.

I've install Postgres locally via the web app and I also installed using Brew Install Postgres.

Comment: These questions are kinda the questions that get answered in introductory tutorials to software like Postgresql and other RDBMS. I don't mean this in a bad way, but it's at least the second such question you ask here. The short answer is: that's not how things work. The long answer is to first learn the ropes, and then try again, or to get professional help from a freelancer.

Comment: I'm a noob. We all were at some point... I don't usually handle the deployment side of projects but this time...

Comment: Yes, I know we all were noobs. But at this stage the basic correct answer is "read the manual". Because anybody that attempts anything else here would be basically rewriting the manual in a poor way. That's why I said that I didn't mean it in a bad way. I'm just saying that this is not the place you should be looking at this point. You need the manual. You need to learn the basics of how things work, and if you're having trouble implementing it and the manual sheds no details about it - ask a question here.

Comment: I was able to push data from my local db to Heroku Postgres DB. But my app still throws an error when I run the deployed version. Possibly an issue with my connection string : connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||  'postgres://<username>:<pg_password>@localhost:5432/<local_db_name>';

Comment: Solved the issue. So for those who stumble across this problem in the future and want to avoid HOURS AND HOURS of torturous research, do the following   ;  )                                                                                                    I am running Heroku via Node and JavaScript. My process.env.DATABASE_URL was coming back undefined so what I had to do was literally use my PG DATABASE_URL as a string and assign that to my connectionString. Two things to keep in mind is this. 1) You must set SLL to true or you will receive an error. Simply do this pg.defaults.ssl = true ...

Comment: And 2) This is only a short term solution because your PG dabase url can change. So I will be adding a way to get the most recent PG database URL running on my app. In the mean time, this method of hard coding at least gives me a sigh of relief and a working app that I can show my boss that works from any computer. ;  )